# iOS UIGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have two questions:

1. Can I implement gesture recogniser that inherits from `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` and add logic to the `UIEvent` handlers?
2. Can I implement `UIGestureRecognizer` without attaching it to a `UIView`? Meaning, I will analyze and manage the `UIEvent` events and call the proper selector (`touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, `touchesEnded`, `touchesCancelled`)?

In the meantime I have problems reseting the gesture recogniser when the state is `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`.

Answer (score 1):

You asked:

> Can I implement gesture recogniser that inherits from `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` and add logic to the `UIEvent` handlers?

Yes. See [Creating a Custom Gesture Recognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH2-SW44) in the *Event Handling Guide for iOS.* Also see [WWDC 2010 session 121 - Advanced Gesture Recognition](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/?id=121). It probably depends upon what you want to do, though, and you should see if you can accomplish what you want by configuring the standard swipe gesture's `direction` and `numberOfTouches` parameters. I've done more subclassing on continuous gestures like `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, but I see no reason why you couldn't do it on a swipe, too.

> Can I implement `UIGestureRecognizer` without attaching it to a `UIView`? Meaning, I will analyze and manage the `UIEvent` events and call the proper selector (`touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, `touchesEnded`, `touchesCancelled`)?

No. Obviously you can create one, but it just won't receive any of the events until it's added to a `UIView` and that view receives touches.

> In the meantime I have problems reseting the gesture recogniser when the state is `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`.

You'd have to submit a new question providing a relevant code snippet for us to help you on that one. In general, you'd do any post-gesture cleanup when your handler is called for `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` (and `UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled` or `UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed`) and you'd initialize everything for the next gesture when you receive the next `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Regarding the second question, as I mentioned, I am managing the UIEvents by swizzling the UIApplication sendEvent: then I forward the UIEvents to the recognizer that is not attached to any UIView. And seems that it works in the first time, but then the state is not rested to possible so the other events fails. Any idea?

Comment: @Amir It's hard to say without seeing code. But I have to confess that I'm not a fan of swizzling as it seems that the law of unintended consequences often comes into play. But maybe create a new question with your swizzling code and see if anyone has thoughts (and brace yourself for the anti-swizzling flames; I'll refrain, though). Can I ask what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Amir I have to wonder, though, whether the UIKit's handling of reverting a gesture's state back to possible is somehow contingent upon it being hooked to a UIView. I really don't know. It's an internal implementation question that I've never contemplated before. But the great thing about S.O. is that there is generally someone who has spent a lot of time thinking about the same problem that you may be wrestling with...

Comment: Thanks Rob! I am just trying to learn iOS,Objective C and it's capabilities.

Comment: @Amir Very good. Best wishes. I notice, though, that you have two questions out there and I really have to wonder what you're trying to do. You haven't explained what problem you're trying to solve. Nine times out of ten, trying to do swizzling or intercepting events, you're going down the wrong road. That sort of code often ends up being very fragile. If you can explain what problem you're trying to solve, we might have far simpler solutions that fall more within the realm of customary iOS development (and are likely to be far more robust).