# override sendEvent

Tags: ios, gestures

I am overriding the `UIApplication` `sendEvent:` with this implementation:

```
-(void) sendEvent:(UIEvent*) event
{
    [super sendEvent:event];
    [EventsHub sendEvent:event];
}
```

When I am receiving event for `touchesMoved` phase in pan gestures, the `UIView` pointer in the touches object become `nil` after executing line 3 ( [super sendEvent:event];).

Can't reproduce this problem when doing any other gesture like swipe or long press in the screen. Only when I do pan gesture.

Any idea?

Comment: Following up on my comment to your other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711720/ios-uigesturerecognizer), can I ask what you're trying to do? This is a very unusual construct.

Comment: I am trying to log all of the user interactions with the device screen. Do you suggest better approach?

Comment: FWIW, I went with this approach as well for implementing a watchdog timer for my application. The other approach with a transparent UIView layered on top of all my views seemed ugly.